# TYPO3 - Mutiple Domain to Single TYPO3 Install?

Tags: php, content-management-system, typo3, typoscript, typo3-flow

I have a site eg: `mysite.com` in TYPO3 and using TemplaVoila as Template Engine. And I want to implement mobile version of the site like `m.mysite.com` into the same TYPO3 installation.

How is it possible ?

Comment: That depends, do yo want to make that on the single PageTree (I'd recommend that approach) or on separate branches?

Answer (score 5):

There's an extension which allows to differ some behaviors basing on (sub) domain, so you can use it for building mobile version... http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/multidomain_publishing, using this you can do exatcly what want.

Additionally use [rtp_imgquery](https://github.com/rtp-ch/rtp_imgquery) for using image size according to device's screen width.

On the quite other hand, instead using subdomains for responsive version, maybe it's better to use ie. [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) for making responsive version of the page at once?

Answer (score 1):

Add the `domain record` and create a condition in TS. I second the answer from besior otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a domain record to the same tree where main domain resides and add a condition with alternative layout definitions in TS.
If the default website works without a condition, than it is possible to just overwrite some of the definitions. By using a special condition for the main domain you can easily split the whole definition.

Example:

> ```
> [globalString = IENV:HTTP_HOST=www.example.com]
> # Basic Layout
> page=PAGE
> ...
> [end]
> # Mobile Layout
> [globalString = IENV:HTTP_HOST=m.example.com]
> page=PAGE
> ...
> [end]
> ```

BUT: usually it is not neccesary to have a separate domain just for having a mobile layout for the same content, in this case you better use the responsive webdesign approach. Than you even avoid double content listings from googles search console.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same page tree (and even the same content), you could use a typoScript condition, to overwrite the whole rendering, for the mobile site.

f.e.

```
[globalString = IENV:HTTP_HOST=www.example.com]
# add your rendering here....

[end]
```